# can lock work across multiple objects in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, locking, critical-section

I have been looking for a way to lock a particular piece of code.

```
namespace x
{
   public class y
   {
      private Object obj = new Object();
      private void A()
      {
         lock(obj)
         {
            //critical section
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Upon request my application enters method A from different sources(which uses class Y) and it is seen that lock object is failing to protect the critical section.

I am looking for the way to protect critical section even though multiple objects try to access the piece of code and i do not want to use static lock object.

Please help me.

Comment: Define `obj` as static.

Answer (score 2):

Lock do the job, but you lock an instance field, it will protect your critical section only for same instance. If you want to lock for all instance, make your flag (Obj) static.

```
namespace x 
{ 
    public class y 
    { 
        static private Object obj = new Object();

        private void A() 
        { 
            lock(obj) 
            { 
                //critical section 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: hi tony, thanks for reply but as mentioned in last lines of question i am not allowed to use static objects

Comment: You can do it by using MethodImplAttribute with MethodImplAttributeOptions.Synchronized

Comment: @bourne the problem is that you **can't** share the instance level lock between objects. You need a singleton here, so it,s either static field or IoC registration for a singleton